# how to remove/hide a content view(UIButton) from extra added rows UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

The below code works fine when i am not adding any extra row all the content view are controlled(hide/visible) but problem when adding to dummy rows.
i am having a table view created programatically.i am initializing my cell with some content view(labels & buttons).I am adding two dummy rows as : if indexPath.row > [mYarray count].I am trying to hide my buttons in extra added rows.BUt when i'm scrolling the buttons are some times hiding from cell or some time displaying in cell.The condition is something like: if(indexPath.row < [mYarray count]) then **buttons MAY(See below code,the condition which decides to hide/visible if(ShowNQButton)) be hide/visible**.But if(indexPath.row > [mYarray count]) then **buttons MUST be hide/invisible/removed.**

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Identifier];



    if (cell == nil) 
    {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:Identifier] autorelease];
        cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;      

        waitTimeLabel=[[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(210, 0, 50, 30)]autorelease];
        waitTimeLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        waitTimeLabel.tag=lblTAG5;
        waitTimeLabel.numberOfLines=2;
        waitTimeLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:waitTimeLabel];

        EstSeatLabel=[[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(270, 0, 60, 30)]autorelease];
        EstSeatLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        EstSeatLabel.tag=lblTAG6;
        EstSeatLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:EstSeatLabel];

    }
    else
    {   

        waitTimeLabel=(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:lblTAG5]; 
        EstSeatLabel=(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:lblTAG6];         

    } 
if (indexPath.row < [UIAppDelegate.waitlistDetailArray count]) {


        NQbutton =   [[UIButton alloc]init];
        NQbutton.frame=CGRectMake(220, 4, 42, 24);
        NQbutton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted=NO;
        NQbutton.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
        NQbutton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;

        UIImage *NQbuttonimage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NqN"];
        [NQbutton setBackgroundImage:NQbuttonimage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [NQbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(NQbutton:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        NQbutton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:NQbutton];
        [NQbutton release];

        NQbuttonEstTime=   [[UIButton alloc]init];
        NQbuttonEstTime.frame=CGRectMake(275, 4, 42, 24);
        NQbuttonEstTime.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted=NO;
        NQbuttonEstTime.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
        NQbuttonEstTime.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;

        UIImage *NQbuttonesttimeimage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NqN"];
        [NQbuttonEstTime setBackgroundImage:NQbuttonesttimeimage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [NQbuttonEstTime addTarget:self action:@selector(NQbutton:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        NQbuttonEstTime.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:NQbuttonEstTime];      
        [NQbuttonEstTime release];

        if(ShowNQButton)//**this BOOL variable is outside of cellForRow decides if buttons  //should be visible or not when indexPath.row < myArray' count.**
        {
            NQbutton.hidden=NO;
            NQbuttonEstTime.hidden=NO;

        }
        else {
            NQbutton.hidden=YES;
            NQbuttonEstTime.hidden=YES;

        }


    } 
else
    {//i have added three dummy rows in numberOfRowsInSection(when indexpath.row > [myArray Count])
        waitTimeLabel.text=@" "; 
    EstSeatLabel.text=@" ";

        //below i am stuffing in removing/hiding these two contentViews from dummy cells 
        NQbutton.hidden=YES;//tried setImage=nil fornormalState//tried removeFromSupViw
        NQbuttonEstTime.hidden=YES;//tried setImage=nil fornormalState//tried removeFromSupViw
    }


}


return cell;
```

}

Any suggestions? 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the dequeue cell. If you look your code, you are adding the two buttons only on the `indexPath.row<[array cont]` Logically its correct. 
So try with solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493598/problem-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier-custom-cell)